# ESLint Definition for rule 'import/extensions' was not found

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintrc, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm getting the following two errors on all TypeScript files using ESLint in VS Code:

```
Definition for rule 'import/extensions' was not found.eslint(import/extensions)
Definition for rule 'import/no-extraneous-dependencies' was not found.eslint(import/no-extraneous-dependencies)
```

A screenshot from VSC Problems pane:

[image]

### Note on possible duplicates

There are many similar questions about different modules and even some about the `import/extensions`, but none of the suggested solutions help. I've tried them all. I also tried every single solution posted in every single thread suggested by Stack Overflow while typing this question.

Here is my `.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
  "env": {
      "es2021": true,
      "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
      "airbnb-typescript/base",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 12,
      "sourceType": "module",
      "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "plugins": [
      "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "rules": {
      "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "off"
  }
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "graph-userdata-gateway",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Gateway for PowerApps Microsoft Graph API custom connector to query user data with application permissions.",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@gitlab.yobitti.fi:powerapps/graph-userdata-gateway.git"
  },
  "author": "Benjamin Pettinen / YO-bitti Oy",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client": "^3.0.0",
    "dedent": "^0.7.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "md5": "^2.3.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/dedent": "^0.7.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/isomorphic-fetch": "0.0.35",
    "@types/md5": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.5.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.2",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^13.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

I've tried deleting the whole `node_mobules` and re-running `npm install` as well as played with the `extends` in the `.eslintrc.json`. If I remove `airbnb-typescript/base` the error disappears, but I lose the Airbnb style from ESLint. Using `airbnb-base` instead works, but then ESLint complains about `Missing file extension for abc.ts` and `Unable to resolve path to module abc`. I have also multiple time restarted VSC and the ESLint server.

Comment: Could you send your repo here, it helps to trace/try the issue more properly?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You missed adding this in your `eslint.json` file.

```json
"plugins": ["import"],
```

Or,

```json
"extends": ["plugin:import/recommended"]
```

Reference: https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import#resolvers

Comment: Thanks a lot! Spent multiple hours trying to fix this yesterday and this little addition to the plugins fixed it once and for all. Weird since I haven't needed this in any previous repositories with the exact same config, but I guess things change even between minor versions of eslint, typescript and the airbnb style guide.

Comment: You get the prize, sir! I've just spent over an hour trying to resolve this, this is a case of 'Only finding what you're looking for in the last place you looked for it!' - why couldn't I have found this first....

Comment: If you do not see the fix take effect immediately: delete the node_modules directory and the package-lock.json file, run npm install and restart your IDE :)

Comment: For those using React 18+/TS/CRA, I recommend using `"plugins": ["import"]`, instead of `"extends": ["plugin:import/recommended"]` because for some reason, you'll get something like `ReportHandler not found in "web-vitals"` for `web-vitals ^2.1.4`.

Comment: Make sure `'import/extensions'` config is nested beneath the `'settings'` node too. Mine was incorrectly beneath the `'rules'` node.

Answer (score 34):

For those coming here after the upgrade of Typescript Airbnb config to v13+ and wants to understand what has changed:

[Read carefully the most recent README of the `eslint-config-airbnb-typescript` project](https://github.com/iamturns/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript/tree/v16.1.0#1-setup-regular-airbnb-config).

> Make sure you have the regular Airbnb config setup. See [`eslint-config-airbnb`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb), or [`eslint-config-airbnb-base`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-base) if you're not using React.

Sounds like something new for your old setup and it really is.
That's because there was a [breaking change in v13](https://github.com/iamturns/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript/releases/tag/v13.0.0)

Let's follow the suggestion.

According to [`eslint-config-airbnb-base` instructions](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/eslint-config-airbnb-base-v15.0.0/packages/eslint-config-airbnb-base#eslint-config-airbnb-base) you should add `eslint-config-airbnb-base` and it's peer deps to your **package.json**. The easiest way to do it: `npx install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb-base`. Right now this command will add both (`eslint-config-airbnb-base` and `eslint-plugin-import`) to your **package.json**:

```json
     "eslint": "^8.7.0",
+    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
     "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^16.1.0",
+    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
```

The final step will be adding `airbnb-base` right before the `airbnb-typescript/base` to `extends` array of eslint config:

```js
   plugins: ["@typescript-eslint"],
   extends: [
+    "airbnb-base",
     "airbnb-typescript/base",
```

That's it! The problem should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was able to fix it by adding the "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" setting to "compilerOptions" in "tsconfig.json".

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `.eslintrc.js` then add this

```
module.exports = {
  ...otherSetting,
  plugins: ["import"],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no problem with the configuration

Problems caused by npm dependency hoisting

The project root directory will rely on the eslint that does not match the promotion installation, because the plug-in reports an error ESLint Definition for rule 'xxx' is not found

Detailed problem solving process in an article I wrote: https://www.yuque.com/cloudyan/faq/py7xb5

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33024012)